# Automator / AppleScript: Batch rotate and crop (and compress)

Tags: image, macos, image-processing, applescript, automator

I'm trying to create a workflow with Automator (or AppleScript) which does the following with multiple images at once (I'm on a Mac as you might guess).

1. Rotate picture to landscape if it's portrait
2. Crop picture to 2048x1536 px (without adding black borders)
3. (if possible: compress image to reduce file size)

Does anybody know how to achieve this?
Would be amazing to have all of this in one Automator Script / Application because I have several thousands of images who need to be rotated and cropped.

Comment: Consider shelling out to [sips](https://ss64.com/osx/sips.html) for points 1 and 2.

Comment: Actually, you can do all of this with sips. I'm happy to whip up a script for you (even though this isn't a scrip-writing site), but I need some details. Do you want the crop to be centered, or cropped from one of the corners? do you want the image scaled on one of the dimensions first, so the crop only takes off two sides? What to do with images that are smaller than these dimensions: border them, expand and crop the other way, process them without size changes?

Comment: Thanks for your answers!
The crop should be centered. There won't be images smaller than 2048x1536 px but if so, it would make sense to expand them. The desired result are images with exactly 2048x1536 px and without any black borders.

Comment: If an image is portrait and you rotate it to landscape there are two possibilities, clockwise or anti-clockwise. One of them will potentially make your picture upside-down...

Comment: *"Compress to to reduce filesize"* - this is dependent on the input images. What type of files are they - TIFF, JPEG, PNG, PSD files?

Comment: Are all the files in a single directory, or are they spread over multiple levels? Should the modified files replace the input files or do you have enough space to write the modified files somewhere else till you have checked them?

Answer (score 1):

Credit this script to the fact that I'm stuck at home and bored. Also credit Apple, since I used parts of one of their template files (File → New From Template → Droplets → Recursive Image File Processing Template)

You run the following script in two ways:

- Straight from Script Editor: Run it, and it will ask you to choose folders to process
- As a droplet: Save the script as an application (choose 'application' from the 'format' pulldown menu on the 'Save' screen), then drag & drop files and folders onto the icon

This script runs through the folder hierarchy looking for image files, and when it finds them it rotates, expands, and crops as needed to get the image to 2048x1536, which it saves in the same folder under the original file name with the tag " - munged" added.

Make sure to back up your image folders first before trying this. Things rarely work perfectly on the first pass.

```
property type_list : {"JPEG", "TIFF", "PNGf", "8BPS", "BMPf", "GIFf", "PDF ", "PICT"}
property extension_list : {"jpg", "jpeg", "tif", "tiff", "png", "psd", "bmp", "gif", "jp2", "pdf", "pict", "pct", "sgi", "tga"}
property typeIDs_list : {"public.jpeg", "public.tiff", "public.png", "com.adobe.photoshop-image", "com.microsoft.bmp", "com.compuserve.gif", "public.jpeg-2000", "com.adobe.pdf", "com.apple.pict", "com.sgi.sgi-image", "com.truevision.tga-image"}

property target_height : 1536
property target_width : 2048
property marker_text : " - munged"

-- choose folders to process if the script is run from scriopt editor
on run
    set these_items to choose folder with prompt "Choose folders to process" with multiple selections allowed
    repeat with this_item in these_items
        process_item(POSIX path of this_item)
    end repeat
end run

-- dropped files and folders enter the stream here
on open these_items
    repeat with this_item in these_items
        process_item(POSIX path of this_item)
    end repeat
end open

-- this sub-routine parces folders to find image files
on process_item(this_item)
    tell application "System Events"
        set this_disk_item to disk item this_item
        -- skip invisible items and processed output
        if visible of this_disk_item is false or name of this_disk_item contains marker_text then return
        if class of this_disk_item is folder then
            set contents_list to disk items of this_disk_item
            repeat with an_item in contents_list
                my process_item(POSIX path of an_item)
            end repeat
        else
            try
                set this_extension to the name extension of this_disk_item
            on error
                set this_extension to ""
            end try
            try
                set this_filetype to the file type of this_disk_item
            on error
                set this_filetype to ""
            end try
            try
                set this_typeID to the type identifier of this_disk_item
            on error
                set this_typeID to ""
            end try
            if (class of this_disk_item is not alias) and ¬
                ((this_filetype is in the type_list) or ¬
                    (this_extension is in the extension_list) or ¬
                    (this_typeID is in typeIDs_list)) ¬
                    then
                my process_image(POSIX path of this_disk_item)
            end if
        end if
    end tell
end process_item

-- this sub-routine processes image files 
on process_image(this_image_path)
    tell application "Image Events"
        set revised_image to open this_image_path
        set {w, h} to dimensions of revised_image
        set desired_scale to target_height / target_width
        if w < h then
            -- portrait mode; rotate
            rotate revised_image to angle 270.0
            -- need to reverse dimensions; image events seems to be working off the saved file, not the rotated image
            set actual_scale to w / h
            if actual_scale > desired_scale then
                scale revised_image by factor target_width / h
            else
                scale revised_image by factor target_height / w
            end if
        else
            set actual_scale to h / w
            if actual_scale > desired_scale then
                scale revised_image by factor target_width / w
            else
                scale revised_image by factor target_height / h
            end if
        end if

        crop revised_image to dimensions {target_width, target_height}

        set new_file_name to my edited_file_name(name of revised_image)
        save revised_image as JPEG in ((POSIX path of (location of revised_image)) & "/" & new_file_name) with compression level medium with icon
        close revised_image
    end tell
end process_image

-- routine to add marker text to revised file names, so we don't overwrite the original data
on edited_file_name(the_file_name)
    set tid to my text item delimiters
    set my text item delimiters to "."
    set bits_list to text items of the_file_name
    if (count of bits_list) > 1 then
        set (item -2 of bits_list) to contents of (item -2 of bits_list) & marker_text
    else
        set (item 1 of bits_list) to contents of (item 1 of bits_list) & marker_text
    end if
    set revised_name to bits_list as text
    set my text item delimiters to tid
    return revised_name
end edited_file_name
```